# SwiftUI - PopToRoot IOS 16

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-navigationstack

In the below code please let me know how to perform popToRoot like from the rewards view to menu view thats my root view , using the navigation stack and navigating through the navigation link & also suggest me how to change the navigation bar title font , text colour navigation back bar button text hidden all those stuffs.

```
struct MenuView: View {
        
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            
            NavigationLink {
                
                ItemsView()
                    .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                
            } label: {
                Text("Go to items")
            }
            
            .isDetailLink(false)
            
            .navigationTitle("Menu")
            
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            
            .toolbarBackground(.orange, for: .navigationBar)
        
            .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
        
            .toolbarColorScheme(.dark, for: .navigationBar)
        }
    }
}

struct ItemsView: View {
    
    @State var isBatSelcted: Bool = false
    
    @State var shouldNavigate: Bool = false
    
    @State var showAlert: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Spacer()
            
            HStack {
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button {
                    isBatSelcted = true
                } label: {
                    Text("Bat")
                }
                .padding()
                .background(isBatSelcted ? .green : Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .clipShape(Capsule())
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button {
                    isBatSelcted = false
                } label: {
                    Text("Ball")
                }
                .padding()
                .background(isBatSelcted ? Color.gray.opacity(0.5) : .green)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .clipShape(Capsule())
                
                Spacer()
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Text("Please click bat and navigate")
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button {
                isBatSelcted ? shouldNavigate.toggle() : showAlert.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Navigate")
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.orange)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .clipShape(Capsule())
            
            Spacer()
        }
        
        .navigationTitle("Items view")
        
        .toolbarBackground(.orange, for: .navigationBar)
    
        .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
    
        .toolbarColorScheme(.dark, for: .navigationBar)
        
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $shouldNavigate, destination: {
            RewardsView()
        })
        
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("Alert") , message: Text("Please select bat to navigate"))
        }
    }
}

struct RewardsView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Text("You got a DSC bat")
                        
            Button {
                
            } label: {
                Text("Pop to root")
            }

        }
        .navigationTitle("Rewards view")
        
        .toolbarBackground(.orange, for: .navigationBar)
    
        .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
    
        .toolbarColorScheme(.dark, for: .navigationBar)
    }
}
```